# Doctrine2 filter query on a child property in class table inheritance

Tags: inheritance, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to filter a Doctrine query made with QueryBuilder on a child property when the object have this property. 
Basically, I have an abstract class `Accommodation` with  `House` and `Tent` as child on a [Class table inheritance, as described in the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance). 
`House` class has a `owner` property and `Tent` does not. 
This is how I make my queryBuilder.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
          ->select('a')
          ->andWhere('(a NOT INSTANCE OF "House") OR (a INSTANCE OF "House" AND a.owner = :owner)')
          ->setParameter("owner", $user);
```

Doing that I get an error saying that `owner` does not exist for `Accommodation` :

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 299 near 'owner =:owner)': Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\Accommodation has no field or association named owner

Is there any way to ask Doctrine to join the `owner` column?

PS: This is part of a Symfony3 project but I don't think it matter for the question.

Answer (score 1):

Reading [those mailing list posts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/JtCbwuN-37o), what I want to do is not possible. So I finally go with 2 queries one one the `Accommodation` Table with a `andWhere(a NOT INSTANCE OF "House")` and a second on the `House` table to get the rest.

That is not really performance optimal but it's the only workaround I see.

If anyone see any other solution, fell free to complete.

Comment: Nice one. How to do with Gedmo\SoftDeletable if filters wont work on half of my tables after being "discriminated" (to get inverse ManyToMany (morphMany) relation)

Doctrine owns you again. And 1000 times more.